# In Hibernate Query Language is there any way to select from the result of Inner Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to select Count of the result Of Sub Query
e.g. 
SELECT COUNT(*) from (SELECT * FROM ENTITY Group By );

Is there any way to do this in HQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

[Hibernate SubQsueries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-subqueries)